# How to efficiently assign a unique number to each string present in a pandas dataframe column, without using 2 for loops?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, for-loop

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Col1':['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Col1'])
df['Col2'] = np.zeros(6, dtype=int)
df
```

[image]

I want to make the entries of `Col2` as following: 1 if `Col1` is A, 2 if `Col1` is B, etc.

My way is to first extract the unique values in `Col1` and assign a number to each of the unique values:

```
uniq_vals_df = pd.DataFrame({'Unique Vals':df.Col1.unique(), 'Numbers':range(1,len(df.Col1.unique())+1)})
uniq_vals_df
```

[image]

And then run 2 for loops to compare and match to assign the appropriate value:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(len(uniq_vals_df)):
        if df['Col1'][i]==uniq_vals_df['Unique Vals'][j]:
            df['Col2'][i]=uniq_vals_df['Numbers'][j]

df
```

[image]

But if the dataframe is big, this would take a long time to finish. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Use `df['Col2'] = pd.factorize(df['Col1'])[0] + 1`

Comment: Use `df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].map(lambda char: ord(char)-64)` if you want to make sure A=1, B=2, C=3, ...